# How to remove an object with a method in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to program something in which a lobster can get eaten by a pelican, but the pelican must disappear after eating said lobster. What code would remove the Pelican from world?

The current (full) code is:

```
import greenfoot.*;

/**
 * Write a description of class Pelican here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Pelican extends Animal
{
    /**
     * Act - do whatever the Pelican wants to do. This method is called whenever
     * the 'Act' or 'Run' button gets pressed in the environment.
     */
    private boolean lobsterEaten=false;
    public void act() 
    {
        randomTurn();
        turnAtEdge();
        lookForLobster();
        move();
    }
    public void randomTurn()
    {
        if(Greenfoot.getRandomNumber(100)<10)
        {
            turn(Greenfoot.getRandomNumber(91)-45);
        }
    }
    public void turnAtEdge()
    {
        if(atWorldEdge())
        {
            turn(17);
        }
    }
    public void lookForLobster()
    {
        eat(Lobster.class);
    }
}
```

Animal code:

```
import greenfoot.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Animal. This is the base class for all animals. In addition to the standard Actor
 * methods, it provides the ability to move and turn.
 * 
 * @author Michael Kolling
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class Animal extends Actor
{
    private static final double WALKING_SPEED = 5.0;

    /**
     * Constructor for Animal - nothing to do.
     */
    public Animal()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Act - empty method. Animals have no default action.
     */
    public void act()
    {
    }


    /**
     * Turn 'angle' degrees towards the right (clockwise).
     */
    public void turn(int angle)
    {
        setRotation(getRotation() + angle);
    }


    /**
     * Move forward in the current direction.
     */
    public void move()
    {
        double angle = Math.toRadians( getRotation() );
        int x = (int) Math.round(getX() + Math.cos(angle) * WALKING_SPEED);
        int y = (int) Math.round(getY() + Math.sin(angle) * WALKING_SPEED);

        setLocation(x, y);
    }


    /**
     * Test if we are close to one of the edges of the world. Return true is we are.
     */
    public boolean atWorldEdge()
    {
        if(getX() < 20 || getX() > getWorld().getWidth() - 20)
            return true;
        if(getY() < 20 || getY() > getWorld().getHeight() - 20)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }


    /**
     * Return true if we can see an object of class 'clss' right where we are. 
     * False if there is no such object here.
     */
    public boolean canSee(Class clss)
    {
        Actor actor = getOneObjectAtOffset(0, 0, clss);
        return actor != null;        
    }


    /**
     * Try to eat an object of class 'clss'. This is only successful if there
     * is such an object where we currently are. Otherwise this method does
     * nothing.
     */
    public void eat(Class clss)
    {
        Actor actor = getOneObjectAtOffset(0, 0, clss);
        if(actor != null) {
            getWorld().removeObject(actor);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: I have no idea whatsoever what you're asking or what problems you may be having. Please have a look at the [help] as well as the [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections for more information on how to improve your question and increase your chances of getting decent help.

Comment: what do your mean by *disappear*? do you mean all references to the object to be lost?

Comment: Tell your pelican to do magic spells using abracardabra so lobster can disappear.. :D :P

Comment: What I mean is that I have a method right now consisting of:
public void lookForLobster()
{
eat(Lobster.class);
}

Comment: edit the question and post your code in the question itself

Comment: But first look at the links that I've provided.

Comment: School assignment. That was what we were told to use and I don't really understand it yet

Comment: Please post **exactly** what you were told to use without alteration whatsoever.

Comment: I am not sure what did you mean by "disappear". If you meant deleting a class, you cant do it. Because class doesnt have any physical existence Only object of that class will have an physical existence.

Comment: Post the Animal as well please.

Comment: Call `getWorld().removeObject(this);` inside of your Pelican's lookForLobster method. Or you could override Pelican's `eat()` method and do it there, but only after calling `super.eat();` first. And thank you, now the question makes sense.

Comment: I'm getting another problem now. The Pelican won't move at all. I get an error message relating to line 21 in the Pelican code, which said "move();" and line 47 in Animal code which described the method move()

Comment: That's another problem entirely and would need another question on this site. If you do decide to ask another question, again, please read the links in my first comment to this question. The site has software that automatically blocks folks who have asked several down-voted questions, and so you will want to avoid this in your future questions.

Comment: Okay then. I'll post a new question. Thanks for all your help hovercraft!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to call `getWorld().removeObject(this);` inside of your Pelican's lookForLobster method. Or you could override Pelican's `eat()` method and do it there, but only after calling `super.eat();` first.